# Is there any way to create dynamic beans in android?

Tags: java, android

I have tried it using dynaBeans as below

```
private static Object createMovieBean() throws Exception {

    // first create the properties
    DynaProperty properties[] = new DynaProperty[] {
            new DynaProperty("title", String.class),
            new DynaProperty("dateOfRelease", Date.class),
            new DynaProperty("keywords", String[].class),
            new DynaProperty("genre", Map.class),
            new DynaProperty("actors", List.class), };

    // next using the properties define the class
    DynaClass movieClass = new BasicDynaClass("movie", null, properties);

    // now, with the class, create a new instance
    DynaBean movieBean = movieClass.newInstance();

    // set its properties
    movieBean.set("title", "The Italian Job");
    movieBean.set("dateOfRelease",
            new GregorianCalendar(1969, 0, 1).getTime());
    movieBean.set("keywords", new String[] { "Italy", "Bank Robbery" });

    Map genre = new HashMap();
    genre.put("THR", "Thriller");

    movieBean.set("genre", genre);
    movieBean.set("genre", "ACT", "Action");

    return movieBean;
}
```

but this gives error log as

```
    03-31 14:09:48.736: E/Trace(674): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-31 14:09:49.355: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-31 14:09:49.365: I/dalvikvm(674): Could not find method java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getName, referenced from method org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties
03-31 14:09:49.365: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4629: Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
03-31 14:09:49.365: D/dalvikvm(674): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00bf
03-31 14:09:49.365: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-31 14:09:49.375: I/dalvikvm(674): Could not find method java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType, referenced from method org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.copyProperty
03-31 14:09:49.375: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4631: Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;.getPropertyType ()Ljava/lang/Class;
03-31 14:09:49.375: D/dalvikvm(674): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01a4
03-31 14:09:49.375: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-31 14:09:49.375: I/dalvikvm(674): Could not find method java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getName, referenced from method org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.describe
03-31 14:09:49.375: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4629: Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
03-31 14:09:49.375: D/dalvikvm(674): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x006a
03-31 14:09:49.385: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-31 14:09:49.395: W/dalvikvm(674): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/MappedPropertyDescriptor; (649)
03-31 14:09:49.395: W/dalvikvm(674): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/MappedPropertyDescriptor;' failed
03-31 14:09:49.395: E/dalvikvm(674): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor', referenced from method org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty
03-31 14:09:49.395: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 861 (Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/MappedPropertyDescriptor;) in Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean;
03-31 14:09:49.395: D/dalvikvm(674): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x01cc
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 647 (Ljava/beans/IntrospectionException;)
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x1b
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean;.fetchIntrospectionData (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospectionData;
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x001b
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean;.fetchIntrospectionData (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospectionData;
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): Verifier rejected class Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean;
03-31 14:09:49.475: D/AndroidRuntime(674): Shutting down VM
03-31 14:09:49.475: W/dalvikvm(674): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674): java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:112)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:63)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:59)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:154)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:75)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(BeanUtils.java:380)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.test.testjson.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-31 14:09:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 14:14:49.575: I/Process(674): Sending signal. PID: 674 SIG: 9
```

I have tried solving the verification exception by compiling the code using 1.6 and 1.7 jdk but it didnt solved it. And it is also giving the error that it could not find class

```
E/dalvikvm(674): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor', referenced from method org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty
```

but it is there in the jar please help.

Comment: Hello from the future. I know it's been a long time but did you ever find a solution? I'm hitting the exact same error

Comment: No, at that time I wasn't able to find any relevant solution, Anyways i think Reflection API might be of some help here, will try it again sometime this week right now i am busy as hell. Will post my findings here.